# jQuery can't get attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get value of `<div class="start1" id="1" point="a1">Start</div>` element, code I use:

```
        $(this).click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("point"));
        });
```

If I put `$(".start1")` instead of this, then value is outputed. What's wrong here ?

Comment: We need to see a bigger scope of your code to understand what happens here. BTW - you better use `data-point` instead of `point`

Comment: Use data-something to keep html5 valid syntax, and remember that now jQuery uses the prop method for anything that's not an attribute (for example, the checked property of a checkbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use data-point instead of point and after retrieve in this mode:

```
<div class="start1" id="1" data-point="a1">Start</div>

$('.start1').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data("point"));
});
```

Comment: It still not solves my problem, I need to use `this` instead of class. Or that is not possible ?

Comment: in this way you can't use $(this) directly, there is no instance of this, or I don't know the rest of the code, if is inserted in other function I don't know @user1876234

Comment: Glad to help you, accept the answer if solved the problem to help other guys with your same problem @user1876234

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `$(this)` doesn't refer to what you want. Maybe you're calling the `click()` function from a wrong scope ?